# How to prevent Castle Windsor from injecting property dependencies?

Tags: .net, inversion-of-control, castle-windsor, property-injection

Is there a way to prevent Castle Windsor from automatically injecting dependencies into properties (besides the [DoNotWire] attribute)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Duplicate: [Windsor Container: How to specify a public property should not be filled by the container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/178611/windsor-container-how-to-specify-a-public-property-should-not-be-filled-by-the-c)

See also:

- http://groups.google.com/group/castle-project-users/browse_thread/thread/f1ec737ff243c19d
- http://jfromaniello.blogspot.com/2009/07/noninjectable-service.html
- http://using.castleproject.org/display/Contrib/Castle.Facilities.OptionalPropertyInjection

Answer (score 1):

If you want to turn off property injection globally, you can use this code:

```
// We don't want to inject properties, only ctors
var propInjector = Kernel.ComponentModelBuilder
                     .Contributors
                     .OfType<PropertiesDependenciesModelInspector>()
                     .Single();

Kernel.ComponentModelBuilder.RemoveContributor(propInjector);
```

(Code sample taken from [Castle Windsor docs](https://github.com/castleproject/Windsor/blob/master/docs/how-properties-are-injected.md) - refer for further details)