# How to Use Windsor without Property Injection

Tags: c#, castle-windsor

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Windsor Container: How to specify a public property should not be filled by the container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/178611/windsor-container-how-to-specify-a-public-property-should-not-be-filled-by-the-c)

I am attempting to use the WindsorContainer, but I need to turn off Property Injection for the entire container.  Here's the code I was trying, but it doesn't seem to have an effect.

```
this.Container = new WindsorContainer(new XmlInterpreter(new ConfigResource("Dependencies")));
this.Container.Kernel.ComponentModelBuilder.RemoveContributor(
  this.Container.Kernel.ComponentModelBuilder.Contributors.OfType<Castle.MicroKernel.ModelBuilder.Inspectors.PropertiesDependenciesModelInspector>().Single()
);
```

I'd rather not use the Attribute [DoNotWire] on my properties because I don't want my application to have to know it's running with Windsor.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.